# How to dpm() an object value?

Tags: debugging

If I run `dpm($form);` I get an array containing objets. Now I need to **just** dpm() the uid of the node object.

How do I do dpm() to isolate an object value?

I tried with `dpm($form['#node']['uid']);` but not working.

Please look the capture to make my question clear:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use:

```
dpm($form['#node']->uid);
```

As you rightly say the `#node` variable is an object, and object properties in PHP are accessed using the `->` operator.

Have a peek at the [PHP Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) documentation for a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your `dpm()` output, you can simply double-click the line of interest and the correct concatenation will expand just beneath that line. See the example on `dpm($node)` below.

Before double-click:
[image]

After double-clicked `target_id`:
[image]